# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '', pls help to fix it

Tags: python, function, input, valueerror

i was learning python and was doing a practice set. when I came upon a error which is saying this here is the whole code, btw code was to print the greatest number and error occurred when entering the input and typecasting it into int.

```
     def greatest(num1, num2, num3):
if(num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num2):
    print("num1 is greatest")
elif(num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3):
    print("num2 is greatest")
elif(num3 >= num1 and num3 >= num2):
    print("num3 is greatest")
int1 = int(input("enter a number1"))
int2 = int(input("enter a number2"))
int3 = int(input("enter a number3"))
greatest(int1, int2, int3)
```

and the error is

```
  enter a number1 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Python\8. Chapter 8\practice.py", line 8, in
  <module>
  int1 = int(input("enter a number1"))
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
  PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Python>
```

Comment: If you don't enter anything, ```input``` returns ```''```. ```int``` cannot convert ```''``` to an integer

Answer (score 0):

Aryan Agarwal There is no issue with the code.
I think you must be pressing Enter without entering any value.

That's why input return '' and int() cannot convert '' to an integer.